# Creating/making a new open/free font (and class for CTAN)?

Tags: fonts, distributions, licensing

This may be a bit wider question, and may relate to Latex not so directly - so  moderators, feel free to move this post elsewhere if more appropriate!

Let's say I like [Caslon (as being used in a magazine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caslon#Williams_Caslon_Text); let's say I scan the text in the magazine with high resolution, and prepare a bitmap image of alphabet table based on the scan. Then, let's say I use this bitmap image as underlay (background) for a software like [fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/editexample.html), where I'd draw the font vectors "by hand", tracing the bitmap outlines - thereby creating a font. So, several questions here:

- Could such a font be legally released afterwards as free/open? If so,

  - what kind of license should be attributed to such a font, so it's considered free/open?
  - Are there any open source (Linux) alternatives to `fontforge` as font creation software?
  - What would be the procedure - and the preferred font format - so that this font can end up on CTAN?

Now, I have also realised that there is an open font [Junicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junicode); and [the Garamond_junicode_caslon comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGaramond_junicode_caslon.png) makes me realize I'd be quite satisfied with it instead of the "real" Caslon I originally fancied. And it is already in CTAN:

```
$ tlmgr search --global --file junicode
tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
context-typescripts:
  texmf-dist/tex/context/third/typescripts/type-junicode.tex
junicode:
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/Junicode.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/Junicode.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/License.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/License.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/README
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/aelfric_job.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/aelfric_job.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/mufi.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/mufi.tex
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/replacements
  texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/junicode/Junicode-Bold.ttf
  texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/junicode/Junicode-BoldItalic.ttf
  texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/junicode/Junicode-Italic.ttf
  texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/junicode/Junicode-Regular.ttf
```

... however, it seems it is distributed as `TTF`, and apparently only ConText (and XeLatex) could use it by default.

So, how would I go about creating a package that would allow usage of this font with `(pdf)latex` -- in the same sense that after installing `tlmgr install palatino`, Palatino can be used via `\usepackage{palatino}`?

- If I'd succeed in making such a package - what would be then the procedure of sharing it through CTAN?

I am aware this is complex matter, which probably cannot be answered in full with a single answer - however, any pointers like links to documentation/tutorials concerning specific parts will be much appreciated!

Comment: If you want an open-source Garamond font, there's [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) which is great. About creating a new font, you should probably get in touch with the guys over at the [League of Moveable Type](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com).

Comment: "Could such a font be legally released afterwards as free/open?" I wouldn't dare to give legal advise here.

Comment: For such old designs like Caslon, you are safer starting from original cuts or old enough samples not contemporary reinterpretations of it.

Comment: Thanks for those links, @Raphink - didn't know about them, looking good :)

Comment: Thanks for the note, @Patrick - I wasn't necessarilly looking for "real" legal advice; maybe rather some links which would have some starting discussion re: legality of tracing fonts and open release.. as I don't even have a starting point in understanding that :) Cheers!

Comment: @Khaled Hosny - thanks for noting that; do you mean "*safer starting from original cuts...*" in legal terms? If so, makes sense - thanks for bringing that up! Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: Yes, that is what I meant.